# Covert JSON data to a chart, then email it using powershell?

Tags: json, powershell

I have a simple powershell script that gets JSON data from an API. I need to take that data, put it in a pretty chart and email it to a list of recipients. I'm pretty new to powershell but I believe (based on Google) there is a ConvertFrom-JSON function that gives me an object I can use. From there, I'm not entirely sure how to create an email and send charts in it.

Comment: You could make the chart in many ways. You could use Excel or JavaScript or a bunch of other things. I would take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331407/powershell-to-create-line-chart-from-excel and then attach your Excel file to your email. If you start down that pathway and have a specific question then that would be more appropriate for this forum.

Comment: There is also charting functionality in PowerShell that I was not aware of until a few minutes ago. This would let you generate an image you can attach: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/richard_macdonald/2009/04/28/charting-with-powershell/