# Charting with PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I want to read a file of data with PS and create a chart in Excel.

In excel I can open a text file and create a line chart of Linux system resources, like this:
[image: Works]

Next,

I copied code from StackOverflow and added my file of data. [$Data=Get-Content "C:\Users...\log.txt" -Raw] ([Complete Code I used here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331407/powershell-to-create-line-chart-from-excel))

What I get from PS is useless:
[image: Garbage]

So how can I read a file of data and create a line chart in PS?

[Ultimately I want to automate this process]

NOTE:
Data file looks like this:

```
Memory      Disk        CPU
 4.96%      70%        0.44%        
 4.96%      70%        0.41%        
 4.96%      70%        0.45%
 etc, etc
```

Comment: The link you provided for the code you used is the question. Perhaps you should reference the answers? Did you check out this answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25333018/1699071

Comment: If you only want a chart, then you can create them directly using the .NET Chart Controls without any need to mess with Excel: [Charting with PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/richard_macdonald/2009/04/28/charting-with-powershell/).

Comment: @SAm  I used the code from TheMadTechnician answer, but tried a text file instead of hard-coading data.

Comment: @boxdog   .NET?  I'm not a windows person outside of Outlook, etc.  Can you paste a simple code snippet of how I might do it?

Comment: @Marinaio the link in my previous comment points to an old (but still relevant) article that gives step-by-step instructions on how to use the chart controls in PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud probably better convert the log file to an array rather that just importing the raw data:

```
$Data = Import-csv "C:\Users...\log.txt" -Delimiter "`t"
```

(Assuming this is a tab-separated file)

The data you see in Excel are not useless, it is just the properties of the PSObject you create using the Get-Content cmdlet, a normal behaviour of the ConvertTo-CSV cmdlet which is used in the code you are using in the line quoted below:

```
$Data |ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "`t"| c:\windows\system32\clip.exe
```

From the [help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv):

> The objects converted from CSV are string values of the original objects that contain property values and no methods.

---

You may also just skip the conversion.

Keep the import using *Get-Content*:

```
$Data=Get-Content "C:\Users...\log.txt" -Raw
```

And remove *ConvertTo-Csv*:

```
$Data | c:\windows\system32\clip.exe
```